I want to fetch the Rolename on the behalf of User Id and this join code Rolname is going nulll
public IActionResult Login( UserDto dto)
 {
     try
     {
         var roleName = (from r in _context.Roles
                         join u in _context.Users on r.UserId equals u.UserId
                         where u.UserId == dto.UserId
                         select r.RoleName).FirstOrDefault();

         if (roleName != null)
         {
             // Set the RoleName in the session
             HttpContext.Session.SetString("Role", roleName);
         }


I'm trying to fetch the rolename on the user id and set the session on the Rolename

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Assuming you are working on asp.net core identity, then in the database, we will have a user table, a user-role table and a role table. User-role table is used to record the user role. https://i.sstatic.net/oTUOorjA.png

In asp.net core Identity, the database has a User table, User-Role table and Role table. If you are working on the same structure, you should join User-Role table at the same time, then the linq shall be similar to:
var query = from user in _context.Users
            join userRole in _context.UserRoles on user.Id equals userRole.UserId
            join role in _context.Roles on userRole.RoleId equals role.Id
            where user.Id == "userId" 
            select new
            {
                UserId = user.Id,
                UserName = user.UserName,
                RoleId = role.Id,
                RoleName = role.Name
            };
var roleName = query.FirstOrDefault();


If you are working on your custom design which doesn't have User-Role table, you should query user table and join role table then the query shall be similar to
var roleName = (from u in _context.Users
                join r in _context.Roles on r.UserId equals r.UserId
                where u.UserId == dto.UserId
                select r.RoleName).FirstOrDefault();

If we can't get the role name, we need to make sure whether the user and role are existing and whether this user has been attached this role in database ahead.
